# Compare 2 Lists Inside Entity Framework Where Clause

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have 3 entity framework entities:

```
public class Tag {
  public Int32 Id { get; set; }
  public String Name { get; set; }
}

public class Book {
  public Int32 Id { get; set; }
  public String Name { get; set; }
  public IList<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
}

public class Post {
  public Int32 Id { get; set; }
  public String Name { get; set; }
  public IList<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
}
```

Given a Book I need to get all the Posts which have exactly the same Tags as that Book.

```
IList<Tags> tags = new List<Tag> { new Tag { Id = 1 }, new Tag { Id = 2 } };

Book book = new Book { Tags = tags };

context.Posts.Where(x => 
  new HashSet<Int32>(x.Tags.Select(y => y.Id)).SetEquals(book.Tags.Select(y => y.Id)))
.ToList();
```

I get the following error:

```
An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Boolean SetEquals(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Int32])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.
```

Any idea how to solve this query?

Thank You,
Miguel

Answer (score 0):

```
from p in context.Posts
let tags = context.Books(b=>b.ID == bookId).Select(b=>b.Tags)//you might need .SelectMany
where p.Tags.All(t=>tags.Any(bt=>bt.Id == t.Id))
select p
```

To do only `lambda` expression, it'll probably be better to get the tags at first, it might be better even in the first option.

```
var tags = context.Books(b=>b.ID == bookId).Select(b=>b.Tags)//you might need .SelectMany

var result = context.Posts.Where(p=>p.Tags.All(t=>tags.Any(bt=>bt.Id == t.Id)).ToList();
```

Comment: I am using lambda expressions since I am using a repository ... Can your code be convert to lambda expressions?

Comment: Not sure why it has to be lambda for repository, but yes it can be done.

Comment: I tried your solution but I get an error similar to what I gad before: An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code. Additional information: Unable to create a constant value of type 'Proj.Data.Entities.Tag'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context. Any idea why?

Comment: Can't translate this request. Its main problem of this.